# Is there a way that you can update noUiSliderInput for two values, when starting them as null?

Tags: r, shiny, nouislider

**Intro:**

I have a list of 40 variables that each has 2000 entries, I am working in R Shiny in order to try automatically divide the data into 3 bins based the value at 1/3 of the data and 2/3 of the data.

Each variable has a range between -10 and 10.

**UI code below:**

```
selectInput("variable","Select your variable",choices = sort(colnames(train))),noUiSliderInput(inputId = "bins", label = "Choose bin width", min = -10, max = 10, value = c(NULL,NULL), orientation = "horizontal", margin = 1, width = 10000, color = "#68228B")
```

**Server code:**

```
  ordered_data <- reactive({
    sort_test <- c(joined_adw[,input$variable])
    sort_test <- as.numeric(unlist(sort_test))
    sort_test <- sort(sort_test)
  })


 eventReactive(

    input$variable,{

 updateNoUiSliderInput(session = session, inputId = "bins", value = c(ordered_data()[667], test()[1334]))
    })


}
```

I know that there are other ways of doing this, but I need the slider in the report sheet.

Any help would be massively appreciated, as I have been trying to do this for a while, and each time I try it, the slider disappears when I use an update call.

Comment: should be ordered_data() not test() for 1334 call.

Comment: Hi, first of all, your example is not reproducible because we don't have access to your data. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to know how to make a reproducible example. Besides, you should add a working (but minimal) ui part, so that we just have to copy the code in your post to have a working shiny app